# How to remove Google search result?

Tags: privacy, google-search

How to remove a Google search result?
It contains my full name and surname and email address like personal information.

Answer (score 4):

Google has a [document](http://www.google.com/support/websearch/bin/answer.py?answer=164734) to remove information.

> You can ask Google to remove your sensitive personal information, like your bank account number, or an image of your handwritten signature, or a nude or sexually explicit image or video of you that’s been shared without your consent, from Google search results.